# Get to the source of malicious .exe

Tags: windows-7, adware

There is an ad-ware worm on my windows 7 PC that I am trying to get rid of. McAfee has been largely unsuccessful. I can see the malicious `.exe` created under the `C:\ProgramData\` folder that is causing the abnormal behaviour: hyper-links on browser when clicked opens a new window with ads.

I deleted the malicious `.exe`file to stop the behaviour but this only helps temporarily as the `.exe` is re-created and ran as a background process.

How can I get to the  root of this problem, i.e. find the program that generates this `.exe` and remove it. Is it possible to trace the generation of `.exe` files or folders in the `ProgramData` folder on Windows 7?

Comment: Use security software to remove the infection.  Trying to do this manually is just a waste of your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had great results using [Hitman Pro](http://www.surfright.nl/en/hitmanpro/). Scans are free, and it will remove malware for free during the 30 day trial period. After that it's $25/year, which is perhaps excessive, given that Hitman Pro is not a full-featured anti-malware solution. But it finds and removes malware better than anything else I've tried.

Answer (score -1):

It does sound like a typical behavior. Something that you really shouldn't need to dig into yourself (unless you're REALLY interested).

Have you tried the "[Malicious Software Removal Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/security/pc-security/malware-removal.aspx)"? It should be worth a try :)

The software searches for and removes any of the unwanted stuff as listed on [this](http://www.microsoft.com/security/pc-security/malware-families.aspx) page. It's made for specific malware and is really thorough with those that it knows how to handle.